# Most reliable method to autosave webform on navigation

Tags: ajax, cross-browser, exit, autosave

What is the most reliable method to autosave a webform on navigation or browser exit by the user?

Suppose you are creating a webmail client, and the user is in the middle of creating a message and they close their browser window. We would like to just save that message as a draft for the user, preferably without having to use the OnBeforeUnload dialogs that are very confusing to users. Are there any very reliable cross browser compatible methods?